# BigQuery Query exceeded resource limits. when using joins with OR

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have BigQuery database and see an error after 30 seconds of execution :

> Query exceeded resource limits. 34012.91515312311 CPU seconds were
>   used, and this query must use less than 20200.0 CPU seconds.

when using such query:

```
SELECT
  b.date as Date, 
  SUM(b.revenue) as Revenue
FROM `dataset.a` a
JOIN `dataset.b` b ON b.id = a.low_id OR UPPER(b.id) = a.high_id
WHERE DATE(a.date_and_time) >= DATE('2020-02-01')
AND DATE(a.date_and_time) <= DATE('2020-02-25')

GROUP BY b.date
ORDER BY b.date
```

I noticed that if I remove grouping and just return `b` records, it will work and last for 40 seconds.
But when I remove `b.id = a.low_id` or `UPPER(b.id) = a.high_id` from the JOIN it works and lasts for 3 seconds!

Could you please explain such behaviour?
And is it real to make this query work without buying additional slots?

Comment: I'm surprised that BigQuery even accepts the query.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  `OR` kills query performance.  And why do you need to use `UPPER()` on the `id` -- but only for one comparison?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I cannot show the data, but can describe it: table a contains information about apple and android installs, android_id and apple_id (apple id is stored in upper case). Table b has information about advertising views, it has field `advertising_id` thet matches android_id field or apple_id field in upper case from table a. Each b recod also has a revenue and date. I want to see revenue by date for specific dates. Each table size is 250 mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this trick.  It constructs an array out of the two ids and then unnests them.  The rest is then just your `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.date as Date, SUM(b.revenue) as Revenue
FROM `dataset.a` a JOIN
     (`dataset.b` bl CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(ARRAY(a.low_id, a.hi_id)) a_id
     )
      ON bl.id = a.a_id 
WHERE DATE(a.date_and_time) >= DATE('2020-02-01') AND
      DATE(a.date_and_time) <= DATE('2020-02-25')
GROUP BY b.date
ORDER BY b.date
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, duration was near 3 seconds! Could you please explain why `OR` kills query perfomance?

Comment: @AlexZaitsev . . . BigQuery does not optimize it correctly.  Obviously the query can be rewritten.  I am guessing that BigQuery sees the `OR` and decides to serialize the query -- eventually running out of resources.